# List of unequal lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
ch_idx = [[1], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2], [3, 4], [3]]
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe where, for each list, index 1 becomes the first column, idx 2 the second column, etc. This means, as the lists are unequal, that some columns will need to be filled with NaN.

Desired outcome:

```
1  NaN  NaN
2   3   NaN
3   4    5
2  NaN  NaN
3   4   NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

NB: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057052/create-a-dataframe-from-a-list-of-length-unequal-lists) does not answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
ch_idx = [[1], [2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2], [3, 4], [3]]
df=pd.DataFrame(ch_idx).set_index(0)
print(df)
```

---

```
     1    2
0          
1  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Note : you can remove the `.set_index()` if you dont want

```
df=pd.DataFrame(ch_idx)
```

Comment: Oh, so simple. Thanks

Comment: Indeed! I was trying more complicated things when the answer was right there. : )